# How can I call a Scala function taking a PartialFunction with a Unit return type from Java?

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

I'm trying to use the scaffolding described by [oxbow_lakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16853/oxbow-lakes) in [What is the easiest way to implement a Scala PartialFunction in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650338/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-implement-a-scala-partialfunction-in-java) to call a Scala method that takes a PartialFunction. Here's my Scala code:

```
class MyScalaClass {
   def instanceOfSomeType: SomeType = ...

   def consume(processor: PartialFunction[SomeType, Unit]) {
      processor.lift(instanceOfSomeType)
   }
}
```

And here's how I'm trying to call it from Java:

```
  MyScalaClass myScalaClass = new MyScalaClass();

  PartialTransformer<SomeType, Unit> fn = new PartialTransformer<SomeType, Unit>() {
     @Override public boolean isDefinedAt(SomeType input) { return true; }
     @Override protected Unit transform0(SomeType input) { return null; }
  };

  PartialFunction<SomeType, Unit> partial = PartialFunctionBridge$.MODULE$.fromPartialTransformer(fn);

  myScalaClass.consume(partial);
```

The compiler tells me:

```
consumeInt(scala.PartialFunction<SomeType,java.lang.Object>) in MyScalaClass cannot be applied
to        (scala.PartialFunction<SomeType,scala.Unit>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `void` as return types in Java to correspond to `Unit` in Scala. Use `scala.Unit` for actual type parameters in generics.

**Update**

I was wrong. You cannot use void on the Java side to correspond to Unit on the Scala side. That's another fiction Scala provides in the reverse direction.

Working on it...

**Update 2**

It seems a lot of methods marked concrete in PartialFunction are created by the compiler. This is proving a lot more tedious than I thought and work beckons.

As usual, accessing Scala from Java is a lot harder than the reverse. Perhaps you can create a Java-friendly API on your Scala side?